# DataTable is taking the incremented numbers as alphabet instead of numeric

Tags: datatables

```
$('#data_tables_one').dataTable( {
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "aoColumns": 
    [
    { "sType": "numeric" },
    null
    ]
});
```

When I hv only the dataTable method without any arguments in it, it was displaying the numbers in the following order
1, 10, 11..19, 2, 20, 21, .....29, 3, 30...

Then I added the **sType** Property, after that strange output came out as follows,

1, **43**, 3, 4......21, **2**, 23, 24.....,41, 42, **22**, 44, 45......

Am i doing any wrong here. Please help.

Here I have added the HTML snippet.

```
<table id="data_tables_one" class="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <td><strong>SL#</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>1</strong></td>
      <td>Marv89</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>43</strong></td>
      <td>yyorkk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>3</strong></td>
      <td>masei</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>4</strong></td>
      <td>Muffin</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Strange. Could you show a snippet of your original HTML table?

Comment: I hv added the HTML snippet

Comment: So setting sType to 'numeric' didn't have any effect, it would seem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the reason that make me stop for about 3 hrs for a silly fix.

The problem for above strange output was the `<Strong>` tag written inside the `<td>`. Anything inside the TD is taken as the data by the dataTables. So after removing that tag from inside that TD i got my result perfectly.

Thanx to everyone, who tried to solve my problem. Thanx.